# Div não centraliza

Tags: html, css

```css
.container-form {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: rgb(22, 20, 20);
    position: relative;
 }

.filha {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: azure;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}

*{   
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-form">    
    <div class="filha">
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ja tentei de tudo e nao consigo centralizar nenhuma div dentro de outra ou qualquer elemento em relação ao body... É como seu eu colocasse 50% em uma direção, mas na pratica é como se fosse uns 70%... Alguem pode me ajudar a resolver esse problema?

Answer (score -2):

Você deve acrescentar `transform: translate(-50%,-50%);`.
Esta propriedade move um elemento de sua posição atual (de acordo com os parâmetros dados para o eixo X e o eixo Y).
Veja resolvido:

```css
.container-form {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: rgb(22, 20, 20);
    position: relative;
 }

.filha {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: azure;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%)
}

*{   
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-form">    
    <div class="filha">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: pode explicar como o `transform: translate(-50%,-50%)` centraliza a div? isso vai melhorar a resposta e o entendimento de quem ler a pergunta, fica melhor do que "usa isso ai" :)

Comment: nossa dar downvote em uma resposta correta, esse stack ta cada vez pior. Esses caçadores de pontos estão descontrolados

Comment: não posso falar pelos outros mas, eu não dei negativo mas acredito que seja por causa da resposta "sem explicação" como eu havia comentado, pois foi edita há pouco tempo, ou talvez pq já tenha uma resposta com a mesma solução